# How to use "/statuses/show/:id"

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I try to use rate_limit_status from the Twitter API:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status

It works fine for: 
data.resources.search['/search/tweets'].remaining;

But I don't understand how to use: 
data.resources.statuses['/statuses/show/:id'].remaining

I would expect to use it like this:

```
T.get('application/rate_limit_status', { resources: 'statuses' }, showRTLimit);

function showRTLimit(err, data, response){
  var showRTLim = data.resources.statuses['/statuses/show/739695095222390785'].remaining;

  console.log(showRTLim);
}
```

But it stills undefined. Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer:

data.resources.statuses['/statuses/show/:id'].remaining